# CoreData in a static library only shows objects as NSManagedObject not the class that I specify

Tags: core-data

I have a static library which uses CoreData. I've copied the .xcdatamodelId in to the IOS application that references the static library, this is so that the .mom file ends up in the main bundle.

I have created core data classes within the static library. If I run the code then the data is retrieved from Core Data correctly but the objects that are generated have the type NSManagedObject.

I've tried copying the generated core data classes in to the main app, this fixes the problem and means that the object is no longer of type NSManagedObject (Since they are in the same bundle.) However the entire static library is based on these Core Data classes and I'd prefer not to move them.

Is there any way that I can tell Core Data to use the classes within the static library?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by subclassing my CoreData classes within my main application and then setting my .xcdatamodelId file to use those classes. This works because the classes are now in the main bundle.